# Call an Actvity from inside a Class

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-activity

I need to call an activity from inside a Class separate which contains a method `onDataChange` of Firebase.

So, I will can call the Activity after Firebase deliver the datas I want. I just don't can get insert a methods `startActivity` or `getBaseContext` of `Intent` from inside my Class.

My class is myUser:

```
public class myUser{
    private static ArrayList<String> userData;

    public static ArrayList<String> getUserData() {
        return userData;
    }
     ...
}
```

My code (INSIDE myUser) is:

```
    public static void setUserData(FirebaseAuth mAuth) {
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    userData = new ArrayList<>();
    String uID;

    uID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    DatabaseReference userRef = database.getReference("users/" + uID);

    userRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String cpf, email, name, tel;
            Boolean depend;
            int uType;

            cpf = dataSnapshot.child("cpf").getValue(String.class);
            email = dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue(String.class);
            name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
            tel = dataSnapshot.child("tel").getValue(String.class);
            depend = dataSnapshot.child("depend").getValue(Boolean.class);
            uType = dataSnapshot.child("uType").getValue(Integer.class);

            userData.add(name);
            userData.add(email);
            userData.add(cpf);
            userData.add(tel);
            userData.add(depend.toString());
            userData.add(String.valueOf(uType));

           //HERE IS WHERE I NEED TO CALL THE ACTIVITY, AFTER GET ALL DATA

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Doesn't matter how I call or instance my class `myUser`. The code is working but it returns error because the `onDataChange` (inside `myUser` class) is ran after activity is open. So, the ArrayList returns null or empty.

This is Why I need to call my Activity from inside of method `setUserData` of my class `myUser`

I've tried to extends my class `myUser` with many other classes withou success.

Comment: You can start an `Activity` from another `Activity`. So, if `myUser` isn't an Activity, you surely call `setUserData` from an Activity: you should start the Activity from there, or at least pass a `Context` parameter to `setUserData`

Comment: Majuran's answer below tells you how to do it. However, if I were you, I'd rather restructure the app so you don't need to start an Activity from a pojo.

Comment: If you are interested in a clean Firebase authentication, you can check this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336).

Comment: Thanks to all. I'm, actually, working in outside for a long time ago and I'm not having time to continue with the code. When I finish with this work, I'll try this answer and return with a response.

Answer (score 0):

Change this method

```
public static void setUserData(FirebaseAuth mAuth) {
```

to

```
public static void setUserData(Context context, FirebaseAuth mAuth) {
```

then call it from your Activity class like this

```
setUserData(this, mAuth);
```

so you can use the activity context inside your myUser class.